# Get Date from Database in HtmlEditor helper tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. I have stored a record in the Database.
When i Edit the record, I can't see the date, instead it shows the Date Picker calender with Default input as "mm/dd/yyyy"

The below is the Code in View file.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.starting_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Type = "date" } })
```

Model Class :

```
public partial class ProjectStatus
{
    public int project_status_id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> starting_date { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: please include you model class.

Comment: Fran, I have updated it

Comment: I am using type "date" in my Table

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the default browser data picker because you've added

Type = "date" in you HtmlEditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.starting_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Type = "date" } })
```

This is invoking the default browser supported date picker.

I would suggest using a viewmodel instead of your domain model as you are currently doing.

Change your model class as follows (I gave your property a nice name for the UI too)

```
public partial class ProjectStatus
{
    public int project_status_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Starting Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? starting_date { get; set; }

}
```

Then use a TextBoxFor and remove Type = "date"

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.starting_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

If you really want to support html5 type declarations you can add it to your model class like this

```
public partial class ProjectStatus
{
    public int project_status_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Starting Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? starting_date { get; set; }

}
```

You can use the jQuery date picker with your date fields

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {

        $("input[type=date]")
            .datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeYear: true })
            .attr("type", "text");

});
```

This will attach a date picker to every instance of in input field that has the html5 type set to date.

You need to have have jquery and jquery ui referenced in your project and page

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. By doing it with Textbox instead of Editor and removing type="date", I am not able to pick the Calender for editing the date. It is just showing the date. But i need to edit as well with Date picker as i got it previously.

Comment: Not all browsers support the datepicker out of the box.  So your user experience may change across browsers.  You can use the second class declaration i included in my answer.  That will tag your starting_date with an html data type tag so that you can still use the internal browser date picker.  i might be better for you to use the jQuery data picker so you have a consistent look and feel across browsers.

Comment: can you help me in implementing this with jquery, i am new to this.